# Could we specify that a quantum space-time (any) belongs to what mathematical spaces? e.g to discrete spaces?

Tags: spacetime, quantum-gravity, discrete

Apparently, there is not a unique and generally accepted definition for a quantum space-time yet. In any case, I'd like to know that, at this stage, could we specify that a quantum space-time (any) belongs to what sorts of mathematical (or algebraic) spaces? For example, discrete spaces? Sorry if the question doesn't make sense somehow.

Comment: More on [discrete spacetime in QG](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[spacetime]+[discrete]+quantum*)

Comment: What do you mean by a "quantum space-time"? While LQG and possibly other theories do change the definition of spacetime, standard QFT and string theory don't really change what *spacetime* is (beyond the number of dimensions). It's not exactly clear what you're talking about to me.

Comment: @ACuriousMind,If it is not clear to you,why do not just leave the question and move on.You see..this question has been answered and the answer has been accepted.

The answer has two upvotes and the question has 5.This means there are people who have clearly understood either or both of them.

Comment: @ItachíUchiha I *did* "leave" the question - I didn't downvote it, I didn't vote to close it, I didn't do anything to it. However, I would like to better understand what the question actually is. What is your problem with that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind,What do you mean by"your problem"?While it is clearly understandable that a negative comment from a highly respected user cum moderator can influence the votes a question receive and I have never refused publicly that your attitude and wording in the comments towards  question should always be the role model  for the community  as it is said to be the best method to maintain the'quality of PSE'.It's not exactly clear what you're talking about to me.

Comment: And a lot's of thanks, love for tolerating this question in spite of being unclear to you,by not closing it.And I am very sorry if I have angered you and other moderators.let the gods and goddess of P.SE. have mercy on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of a discrete space-time is a form of quantum gravity commonly known as [loop quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) (there are many variants on this theme with different names). Lee Smolin is one of the leading investigators in this approach, but it faces issues with Lorentz invariance violations in many formulations which is strongly disfavored experimentally. In those theories, the number of dimensions is often an "emergent" property of the deeper structure of spacetime as is the concept of locality.

Many versions of [string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) require 10 or 11 dimensions of space time, usually with all but four either "compactified" or with all particles except gravitons confined to a four dimensional "brane."

The most common kinds of dimensions are continuous and smooth dimensions that map to the real numbers, those that map to the complex numbers, and finite dimensions. Various topologies of space-time are possible with those that have concave curvature, convex curvature, and torus topology making up the most notable exceptions to flat space-times.

The usual space-time of the Standard Model of Particle Physics is called "[Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space)"

Comment: Thanks for recommending the interesting works of Professor Lee Smolin. Very useful. By the way, a few days ago he has published also a paper in this regards in arXiv: ("*Four principles for quantum gravity*," arXiv:1610.01968, Oct 2016).

Comment: I've read the paper and commented on it a bit at my blog. http://dispatchesfromturtleisland.blogspot.com/2016/10/gravity-modification-from-quantum.html I rated the analysis outlined in the paper as "plausible" but "not rock solid."

Answer (score 0):

The influence of mass on the space-time geometry can be described with quantum theory, where we can state the expected effect of mass on curvature of space-time.

Also it can be theorized that if mass has influence on space-time curvature, in quantum situations where mass does not curve space-time at measured coordinates, it will have done so at other coordinates. The probability of mass affecting space-time in normal situations equals the general relativity (GR).

At extreme situations such as Big Bang and black holes, the behavior of mass differs from "normal" situations. The effect of gravity, bringing particles in closer proximity, increases the chance of two particles taking up the same coordinates in space-time, which is impossible. The chance of dislocation thereby increases.

It is due to this dislocation that there is no such thing as singularity. GR calculations of minimum radius of the mass contained confirm this too. It is for this reason the big bounce theory becomes more popular again.

All matter turns into dark matter over time due to gravitational pull/Higgs field interactions, creating micro black holes throughout the universe (dark matter). These continue their existence until they clog together, bounce back etc.

Comment: *"All matter turns into dark matter over time due to gravitational pull/Higgs field interactions, creating micro black holes throughout the universe (dark matter)."* - we don't even know what dark matter *is* currently, and surely we don't know that it's "micro black holes". We also can't describe *"the influence of mass on the space-time geometry"* with quantum theory, a theory of quantum gravity is what we are still *searching for*. This answer is false in almost every sentence.